# Need help to trim a string in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a filename like this:

```
\workspace\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5\
```

and i want `\folder3\folder4\folder5\`

folder `\folder3\` is constant. Anything before and after can vary but i need all from folder `folder3` and after.

How can i trim the string using bat?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trimming a constant length, or are you removing the three leftmost directories? The two actions are completely different.

Comment: folder \folder3\folder4\folder5\ is constant. Anything before that can vary by users fodler structure

Comment: And is it the literal string "\folder3\folder4\folder5\" or do you just need the last three folders in the path name?

Comment: i need the names.
so i can add a new path in front lik C:\tet1\test\folder3\folder4...

Comment: if it's constant - why trimming? Why can't you use the constant string?

Comment: I use this right now:
SET filename=C:%~dp0
For %%A in ("%filename%") do (
    echo path: %%~pA
    echo file name only: %%~nA
    echo extension only: %%~xA
    echo name.ext: %%~nxA)

file name is the path to my TFS workspace which is different from each user. The last 3 subfolder are the same for every one, which is why i need to trim the first part away.

Comment: again: if it is always the same - is there a reason why you could not use a fixed string?

Comment: Ahh sorry. folder3 is constant, folder4 and 5 vary

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37726756/edit) your question and put the clarifications and your used code there!

Comment: Question is updated :)

Comment: ah - now it makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace [from the start until (including) the fixed string] with [the fixed string]:

```
set "string=\workspace\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5\"
set "string=%string:*\folder3\=\folder3\%"
echo %string%
```